# Replacing header-name in fasta-file and replacing filename in folder, with string from separate file

Tags: python, fasta

I'm doing a bioinformatic study, where I process some data and get some outputs into some desired folders. The folder/file structure looks like this, for two of the folders (Files and folder structure is linked in the end of the thread):

binned/90-20-09-2018/bins/90-20-09-2018.001, 90-20-09-2018.002, 90-20-09-2018.003 and so forth

binned/90-25-04-2018/bins/90-25-04-2018.001, 90-25-04-2018.002, 90-25-04-2018.003 and so forth

I know the amount of folders, but the amount of files in the folders, is unknown and will vary.

In another file called taxonomy (eg. binned/90-20-09-2018/bins/quality/taxonomy.txt) is a table of bacterial names for each of the bins (the files named 90-20-09-2018.001, 90-20-09-2018.002 etc.). As you can see, for each bin ID is a corresponding Taxonomy.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Bin Id              # unique markers (of 43)   # multi-copy   Taxonomy                                                                                              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  90-20-09-2018.001              25                   15        k__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes;c__Bacilli;o__Lactobacillales;f__Lactobacillaceae;g__Lactobacillus          
  90-20-09-2018.003              24                   0         k__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes;c__Bacilli;o__Lactobacillales;f__Streptococcaceae;g__Streptococcus          
  90-20-09-2018.002              15                   0         k__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes;c__Bacilli;o__Lactobacillales;f__Lactobacillaceae_2;g__Lactobacillus_2      
  90-20-09-2018.005              14                   11        k__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes;c__Clostridia;o__Clostridiales;f__Lachnospiraceae                           
  90-20-09-2018.004              12                   0         k__Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Actinobacteria;o__Actinomycetales;f__Actinomycetaceae;g__Mobiluncus  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I need, is to rename each of the bin files (90-20-09-2018.001, 90-20-09-2018.002 etc.) into their corresponding taxonomy (genus) name. The genus name is the name that comes after "g". So for bin 001, it would be "Lactobacillus".

So the final result would look like this (for the first folder).

binned/90-20-09-2018/bins/Lactobacillus, Lactobacillus_2, Streptococcus *and so forth*

I imagine this being done with Python (the only programming language I'm familiar with).

Furthermore, I need to change the headers of the fasta-files, into their corresponding names (the same name as the file itself). The format of the fasta-files look like this:

```
>NODE_2_length_62925_cov_23.488138
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCTTTTCAAGCAGAAGACGGCATACGAGATAATGAGCGGTG
ACTGGAGTTCAGACGTGTGCTCTTCCGATCTCGTCTCAAGTTAAAAATCTGCTAGCCAATACTTTACCTA
ATGCTGTCACTTCTCTACTACAATTTTTCGGTGCATTAGTAATTATGATGGCGATGGATTGGCAAATGAC
CTTGATTATGTTTATCGCCGTTCCACTGGTAGTTGTGGCTCTACTCCCAATCATGCAACAATCACGTAAA
ATCGGCCGTAAGCGCCAGGACGAACTAGCCAACTTTTCAAGCGATTCTACCAGTGTTTTAAGCGAAATTA
GATTAGTTAAGTCTTCCAACGGTGAACCAAAAGAGTTAAACGTTGGAAGCAATCGGATTTCTAGCCTCTA
>NODE_89_length_21285_cov_31.129560
GGCTACAAACAAATTGAAGATGAAATTGCTCGCTTAAAGAAGGGTCGTCCACGCAGAATTAAAATTTTGC
AGGCAGCACGTGCGCTCGGCGACCTTTCAGAAAATACGGAATATACTGAAGCTAAGCGTTACTTAGGCAA
ACAATTAAAGTATACGGAAATCGTTGAAACTAAGGACGATGGCAAGGTTGATTTGGGCAAAACCGTTGTC
TTGAAGTTTGACGATGATGAAGATACTGAAGAATATAAGATTGTTGGCCGGATGGAGGCTGATTTAGCCG
ATGGCAAGATTTCCTTTGGTTCACCACTGGGCCAAGCAATTATGAAAAAAGAGGCAGGGACGACTTCAAC
AGTTGAAGCACCGGCCGGAGAATATAAGGT
```

So basically, it is the names after ">" that need to be changed into their corresponding names.
so for bin 001, it would be "Lactobacillus", for all the headers.

Feel free to ask questions if I've been too unclear.

Thanks!

Link to files and folders:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ho3ux5wplv7yk4u/AAAuqLOFKtxXr3KTwGqca778a?dl=0

Comment: You have been perfectly clear.  However, you have not made a start on any code.  I would break the problem into ~5 steps and write a distinct bit of code for each: 1) traverse the directory structure so that you can open each data file 2) open the taxonomy file and load it into a suitable data structure (e.g. a pandas dataframe or list-of-lists) 3) match each filename to the corresponding row in the data structure 4) rename the file 5) correct the header.  Feel free to edit your question (include some code) if you get stuck with any particular step.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
I didn't start, because I'm quite rusty when it comes to Python coding, however I will try to follow your suggestions!
Do you reckon it could be done with only bash (I'm currently working in a linux terminal)?

Comment: Yes, navigating directories and finding/replacing text can be done just as easily with bash.

Comment: Alright, any will do really.
I must admit, I'm pretty oblivious as to how to approach it. 
Any example code would be appreciated.